# SAM-local fails to start API with multiple stacks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-sam

I want to add resources to my root stack  and somehow found a function where I can first get stack first like this

```
   my_api = RestApi.from_rest_api_attributes(self, "RestApi",
                                               rest_api_id='test',
                                               root_resource_id='test'
                                

           )
```

**reference** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/README.html#breaking-up-methods-and-resources-across-stacks

and then trying to add resources after getting this stack

```
mine_ = my_api.root.add_resource("mine")
mine_.add_method(
            http_method='GET',
            authorizer=api_authorizer
        )
```

on this I am getting this error

**ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash**

any help would be highly appreciated ..

**Edit full traceback of error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "samcli/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
  File "click/core.py", line 782, in main
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/iac/utils/helpers.py", line 55, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/_utils/iac_validations.py", line 79, in wrapped
  File "click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
  File "click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 174, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/telemetry/metric.py", line 141, in wrapped
  File "samcli/lib/utils/version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
  File "samcli/cli/main.py", line 90, in wrapper
  File "samcli/commands/local/start_api/cli.py", line 128, in cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/start_api/cli.py", line 205, in do_cli
  File "samcli/commands/local/lib/local_api_service.py", line 68, in start
  File "samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 173, in create
  File "flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
  File "flask/app.py", line 1275, in add_url_rule
  File "werkzeug/routing.py", line 666, in __init__
ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash
[8038] Failed to execute script __main__
```

Comment: Did you intend to specify a second parameter in you call to `add_method`? Because you have a comma after http_method=GET, so the API expects the URL which points to the integration. Try removing the comma..

Comment: @PankajSaini there is another parameter in actual . just tried to make a minimal  example to post here .

Comment: @PankajSaini a trailing comma is recommended by PEP8 in that case and is definitely not an issue: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#when-to-use-trailing-commas

Comment: What's the line that generates the error? Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

`urls must start with a leading slash` is not an error that CDK throws. It's a werkzeug error, you can see the code in question [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/c7ae2fea4fb229ffd71187c2b665874c91b96277/src/werkzeug/routing.py#L703).

So the error doesn't have anything to do with your CDK code.

The reason for the error is that SAM does not support testing multiple stacks at this point. So either compile everything into a single stack, or avoid using `sam-beta-cdk`.

Comment: I didn't used flask . just using  sam-beta-cdk to build api-gateway across the stack

Comment: So the error isn't during `cdk deploy`? Does it synth and deploy fine? Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: no error is during  `sam-beta-cdk local start-api`  and traceback is updated